# Copy artifact to specific location

Tags: java, maven, deployment

I have an artifact on nexus repo. I can download artifact using `dependency:copy` plugin, but I want to deploy a specific artifact (sometimes may be some config files) to a specific location in delivery product.

Is there a way to handle this using maven?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. Are you wanting to configure your build output to include a specific artifact?

Comment: Thx for the replay Jones... I just want to do build out put to move specific  location to bundle them. Please help me if you are clear

Comment: Do you mean you want to put a 3rd party artifact like a dependency that is not available publicly in your nexus repo?